# Error reading json file in python - AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

Tags: python, json, geopandas

Attempting to read `json` file for us county boundaries and running into some issues. Here are the two ways I tried, without any luck.

```py
# Read US County geo data file
file_path = open(os.getcwd() + "/data/map/us_county/gz_2010_us_050_00_500k.json")

for f in file_path:
    json.load(f.decode("utf-8","ignore"))
```

Another approach I tried that didn't work as well:

```py
with open(file_path, 'r') as j:
    gpd_countyJSON = json.loads(j.decode("utf-8","ignore"))
```

Sample contents of `json` file object:

```json
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "GEO_ID": "0500000US01029", "STATE": "01", "COUNTY": "029", "NAME": "Cleburne", "LSAD": "County", "CENSUSAREA": 560.100000 }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -85.388717, 33.913044 ], [ -85.380885, 33.873508 ], [ -85.379455, 33.866291 ], [ -85.377426, 33.856047 ], [ -85.376403, 33.850656 ], [ -85.364595, 33.788446 ], [ -85.361844, 33.773951 ], [ -85.360491, 33.767958 ], [ -85.357402, 33.750104 ], [ -85.355252, 33.739245 ], [ -85.344054, 33.682684 ], [ -85.342722, 33.675953 ], [ -85.323792, 33.580339 ], [ -85.315340, 33.537646 ], [ -85.314994, 33.535898 ], [ -85.314843, 33.534951 ], [ -85.314091, 33.530218 ], [ -85.313999, 33.529807 ], [ -85.304439, 33.482884 ], [ -85.308211, 33.481579 ], [ -85.309250, 33.483137 ], [ -85.314852, 33.487603 ], [ -85.316028, 33.488267 ], [ -85.320893, 33.488359 ], [ -85.324856, 33.489161 ], [ -85.331061, 33.491014 ], [ -85.338280, 33.494700 ], [ -85.342544, 33.495961 ], [ -85.344923, 33.497608 ] ] ] } } ] }
```

I'd like to turn the data into geopandas dataframe.

Comment: Looks like you might be missing some closing brackets on the end of that json, but that's unrelated to the issue you're having

Comment: The current closing brackets at the end of your sample are `] } } ] }`
They need to be `] ] ] } } ] }`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the decode function in there, all you need is to load with the `json.load()` function that can take a filepath directly.

I'm always a fan of using the context manager to open a file so that closing it is taken care of automatically

```
import json
import os

file_path = os.getcwd() + "/data/map/us_county/gz_2010_us_050_00_500k.json"

with open(file_path, 'r') as j:
    gpd_countyJSON = json.load(j)
```

Comment: I get this error: `TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.TextIOWrapper`

Comment: Are you running just my code block or do you still have your original `file_path = open(os.get_cwd()....` in there? You get that error if you call `open()` on an existing file object. The `file_path` variable in my block is just a string

Comment: Original `file_path`. Here's what it looks like: `file_path = os.getcwd() + "/data/map/us_county/gz_2010_us_050_00_500k.json"`

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is, you're reading the file line by line and want to deserialize it by `json.load`. It's not how it works.

You will need to read the whole data as string and pass it to `json.loads`.

```
import json

with open("data.json", "r", encoding="utf-8") as the_file:
    print(json.loads(the_file.read()))
```

or create the file object and pass it to `json.load`.

```
import json

with open("data.json", "r", encoding="utf-8") as the_file:
    print(json.load(the_file))
```

Please not your json file is not correct. (And too big for me fix it.)

Comment: using `json.load` and `json.loads`, I run into: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf1 in position 13337350: invalid continuation byte`.